# Find the density function of X+Y, where X and Y are random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, density-function

If $X$ and $Y$ have joint density function $f(x,y)=\frac{1}{2}(x+y)e^{-x-y}$ when $x,y>0$ (and $0$ otherwise), find the density function of $X+Y$.

Let $Z=X+Y$. Then from my textbook, it says that $f_Z(z)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{x,y}(u,z-u)du$, where $u=x, u>0$. When I plug the joint density function into this equation, I get $f_Z(z)=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2}ze^{-z}du$. This integral doesn't evaluate because you would have a $u$ being evaluated at infinity. The answer in the book says $f_{X+Y}(u)=\frac{1}{2}u^2e^{-u}$ for $u>0$. I don't see how this is the answer.

Comment: Your formula works for independent random variables.  $x$ and $y$ are not independent.

Comment: Correct formulation, simply a misstep in the integration limits as pointed out by Gregory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You made a small mistake:
$$ f_Z(z) = \int_0^{\color{blue}{z}} \frac{1}{2} ze^{-z} \ du = \frac{1}{2} z^2 e^{-z}$$

**EDIT:** One way to obtain this formula is to consider new variables $U = X$ and $Z = X+Y$. The Jacobian for this transformation is 1 and so
$$ f_Z(z) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{U,Z}(u,z) \ du = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{X,Y}(u,z-u) \ du. $$

Comment: Correct @Gregory.

Comment: Can you tell me where to find that procedure?  Because I have Ross in front of me and it says that procedure works for independent variables and doesn't say about dependent.

Comment: There is no need to use independence.

Comment: This is the general case as @Gregory notes. When $X$ and $Y$ are independent the joint distribution factors and you get $f_Z(z) = \int_R\, f_X(z-y)f_Y(y)\, dy.$

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is to transform the variables from $X,Y$ to $Z,W$ where $Z = X+Y$ and $W = X-Y$.  The Jacobian is $-2$.  So

$$f_{W,Z}(w,z) = \frac{1}{2} f_{X,Y}\big(\frac{1}{2}(z+w), \frac{1}{2}(z-w)\big)$$
Plugging in, we get
$$f_{W,Z}(w,z) = \frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{2}(z)e^{-z}$$
The limits of the domain are $z$ from $0$ to $\infty$, and for a given $z$, the limits of $w$ are ${-z}$ to ${z}$.  So if we integrate over $w$ to find the marginal distribution for $z$, we get
$$ \frac{1}{4}ze^{-z}\cdot 2z = \frac{1}{2}z^2e^{-z}$$